# How to find the largest values of unique pairs?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can find the largest number in the 'value' column for each unique pair of 'location' and 'id' columns?

```
import pandas as pd

data_1 = {'location':['001','001','002','002'],
          'id': ['1100','1100', '2200', '2200'],
          'value': [1, 10, 2, 2]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1, columns=['location','id','value'])
```

So, the output should look like:

```
  location    id value
0      001  1100    10
1      002  2200     2
```

Comment: `df1.sort_values('value').drop_duplicates(['location','id'],keep='last')
`

Comment: `df1.groupby(['location', 'id']).max().reset_index()`